# Set z-index with content overflowing to brother components

Tags: css, z-index

We have two components that are brothers and each one declares its own stacking context. The components can be collapsed, so only the header with some dropdowns are visible.

[image]

When being collapsed, the dropdown menus overflow its content and should be visible on top of its brothers. Since the `z-index` of the dropdowns is inside the stacking context of its parent, it works for displaying on top of elements in the same component, but fails to be on top of the brother component, because it is added later in the DOM.

[image]

How can I set the z-index so the dropdown menus are displayed on top of the brother components?

**Note** I can not set a decreasing `z-index` sequentially to each component, so components that are first are displayed above. In the picture the dropdown menu is opened pointing down but it could also be open pointing up.

Comment: Can't you use Javascript to change the z-index on hover?

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to check if there was a simpler path not involving javascript manipulations. Thanks